# How Android Location Service can wake-up an application when detecting some location

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

What I need is to enable android location service and to set the current location as a destination, then when I close the application and going to another location and coming back to the original location (or when I will be close to the original location) I want the location service to identify that I am now in the original location and to turn on the application again (and to perform something).

How I can Do this on Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) that registered to an event (like boot completed or started by user). Then you need check if your app has permissions to get locations. Lastly, register a listener to location service and track user. Your buisiness logic starts from here.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Create the geofence around your current location,it will detect when you will enter to this fence.

here the link about geofence: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

You can search some other examples about Geofence in android.